# Wrap text based on axis limits instead of chart limits, twinx matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-wrap, twinx

I have been trying to wrap the text in a chart made with matplotlib.  My problem right now is I made the chart using twinx but the text I want to wrap is wrapping in regards to the whole chart instead of the axis I want it to only be on. I don't want the text to overlap with the bars.  Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

```
for i in stocks:
   #WRITE PIPELINE
   ppp = PipelineData['Ticker']

   ccc = PipelineData['Catalyst']
   cc = ccc.loc[ppp==i]
   label = cc+str("      ")
   #label = [ '\n'.join(wrap(l, 50)) for l in label ]
   
   dd = PipelineData['Drug']
   drugs = dd.loc[ppp==i]
   drugs = drugs+str("     ")
   #drugs = [ '\n'.join(wrap(drugs, 35)) for d in drugs ]


   pp = PipelineData['Phase']
   p = pp.loc[ppp==i]

   disdis = PipelineData['Disease']
   dis = disdis.loc[ppp==i]
   
   figure = plt.figure(figsize=(11,6.3))
   ax1 = figure.add_subplot()
   ax2 = ax1.twinx()

   width = 0.7 # the width of the bars
   ind = np.arange(len(p))  # the x locations for the groups
   ax1.barh(ind, p, width, color="#67a362", align='edge')
   ax1.set_yticks(ind+width/2)
   ax1.set_yticklabels(drugs, minor=False, fontname= 'Times New Roman', wrap=True)
   ax1.set_ylabel('Drug', fontname= 'Times New Roman', wrap=True)
   ax1.set_xmargin(1)
   ax1.autoscale_view()
   
   ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
   ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(len(label)) + width/2)
   ax2.set_yticklabels(label,horizontalalignment = "right", fontname='Times New Roman', wrap=True) #CAN CHANGE HORIZONTALALLIGNMENT HERE 
   ax1.spines['right'].set_color('None')
   #ax2.autoscale_view(scalex=False)
   #ax2.spines['right'].set_color('None')
   
   plt.xticks(np.arange(5),('Pre-clinical','Phase I','Phase II','Phase III', 'Approved'), fontname='Times New Roman', wrap=True)
   plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad']=-12
   plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False
   plt.rcParams['font.family']='serif'
   plt.rcParams['font.size']=12.5
   ax1.grid(False)
   ax2.grid(False)
   ax1.set_facecolor('w')
   ax2.set_facecolor('w')

   for bar, disease in zip(ax1.patches, dis):
       ax1.text(0.1, bar.get_y()+bar.get_height()/2, disease, color = 'black', ha = 'left', va = 'center')

   
   figure.savefig(str(i)+'newpipe.png', bbox_inches=None, wrap=True)
   ws.insert_image(row_pipe,col_pipe,str(i)+'newpipe.png',{'x_scale':.56, 'y_scale':.56})
   row_pipe += page_len
   
   
   plt.close(figure)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the wrap functionality of ax.text:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,4)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)
string = 'this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long string'
txt = ax.text(1, 1, string, ha='left', rotation=0, wrap=True)
txt._get_wrap_line_width = lambda : 200
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can follow this [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap.html).

Here is the figure generated by my code above:
[image]